# Is it possible to emulate locally an AWS t2.micro instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emulation, qemu

I wonder if it is possible using qemu or VirtualBox (or VMWare) to fully emulate a "t2.micro" instance so a disk image of /dev/xvda could be booted in a local emulator... I found nothing about this but it would be interesting.

Comment: and.. what would be difference of running a normal linux distribution? (with 20% baseline cpu)

Comment: Do you wish to emulate the performance of the hardware, or are you simply looking for an equivalent OS distribution?

Comment: I got a starting result by doing: qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=xvda.img -nographic -serial mon:stdio  now I have to figure out the networking part

Comment: @gusto2 the difference is that in this way I can backup locally an amazon VM, do some testing and then use the xvda image as a starting point for more VMs

Comment: Then AWS Export/Import may be useful to you https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/

Comment: Yes.. the vm import/export is nice... anyway the image of /dev/xvda  just works. t2.micro instances use XEN virtualization.